# Using a TabbedView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a TabbedView Activity with 3 tabs. Currently, only the 1st tab has its correct icon, and the other 2 are blank.

My xml file is as follows:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/news" android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/score" android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/schedule" android:state_selected="true" />
</selector>
```

The news icon is the one that shows up. Here is my tabbed view activity. I was expecting to see the 2nd tab icon be the score icon, and the 3rd tab be the schedule Icon:

```
        //Headlines
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HeadlineBoard.class);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.SPORT_NAME_EXTRA, sportsName);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.HEADLINES_FOR_SPORT_EXTRA, headlines);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("news").setIndicator("Headlines",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.hl_aggie))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    //Scores
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ScoreBoard.class);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.SPORT_NAME_EXTRA, sportsName);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.SCORES_FOR_SPORT_EXTRA, scores);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("score").setIndicator("Scores",       
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.hl_aggie))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    //Schedule
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ScheduleBoard.class);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.SPORT_NAME_EXTRA, sportsName);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.SCHEDULE_FOR_SPORT_EXTRA, scheduleIn);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("schedule").setIndicator("Schedule",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.hl_aggie))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);       
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

Comment: Are you sure all can be android:state_selected="true" ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I want all the icons to show up, and I don't need a separate icon for selected/unselected. But what I notice is when I select one of the other tabs, then, the same news icon shows up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want all the icon to show up, why don't you just set all the icon drawables respectively to each tab ?

`TabSpec scoreSpec= tabHost.newTabSpec("score");`

`scoreSpec.setIndicator("scores", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.score));`

Here is the [Reference](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)..